# external "harddisk" is detected -- but not readable

Tags: external-hard-drive

I have an external Seagate hard disk. Once I plugged it into computer, I am able to get a new drive detected, e.g. E:. However, at the time I try to read E drive, it is unreadable.

I have tried the following without good outcome

1. try at different PCs
2. change cable
3. using DOS prompt to change drive

Do you have better idea to overcome this or explanation of the situation?

Comment: Is the drive formatted?  If so, what filesystem is on it?  Do you have data on the drive?  What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: the drive was working before, NTFS format, i have data inside, using Windows,  thanks for your comment Matthew, any idea?

Comment: try `chkdsk e:` yet?

Comment: it gave me this error "Cannot open volume for direct access." while trying to run chkdsk

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried mounting that drive under a Linux system? I have run into NTFS difficulties in the past where the volume would not mount under Windows, but would mount under Linux.

Comment: hmm.. that's sounds a good idea, but frankly i don't have ready linux environment on hand..

Comment: Head over to www.ubuntu.com, you can boot their CD in "demo" mode which is actually a fully functioning system (file system, networking, etc.). There's a few others with similar capabilities too, if you have a specific preference.